# Apply scaler, PCA and random forest pipeline to 3D array

Tags: python-3.x, pipeline, scale, random-forest, pca

I have a 3D array for X_train and X_test.  Is it possible to use a `scaler`, `PCA` and `Random Forest` pipeline to the 3D array?  I tried using the code below, however, I get the error:

`ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2.`

If possible, how do I go about correctly using the pipeline below for the 3D array?

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),
('pca', PCA(n_components=15)),
 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])

# Declare a hyperparameter grid
parameter_space = {
    'clf__n_estimators': [10,50,100],
    'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'clf__max_depth': np.linspace(10,50,11),
}

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameter_space, cv = 5, scoring = "accuracy", verbose = True) # model


pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```